# How To Find the Generating Function of the Following Problem

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I need to find the generating function of the following problem:

$d_n$ (for every natural number $n$) is the number of combinations to put coins into an automatic machine whereas the sum of the coins is $n$. There are coins of 1,10 and 25 cents and the amount of each coin is not limited.

While I can find the generating function when the order in which the coins are put into the machine doesn't matter, I don't have any idea in the case when the order do matter.

I know that it can be solved with exponential generating functions, but I wonder if there is any solution with "regular" generating functions.

Comment: I don't think you need EGF's here.  If the order of coins doesn't matter, you can first choose how many 1-cent coins you want, then the number of 10-cent coins, then the number of 25-cent coins.  If the order of coins does matter, then you have an infinite sequence of choices - at each step, choose 1- or 10- or 25-cent coins.

Comment: How did you do it when the order of the coins doesn't matter? Use an exponential generating approach? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454193/integer-partition-in-k-parts-from-a-specific-set-s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Im not wrong I think that the following

$$d_n=[x^n]\sum_{k=1}^\infty(x+x^{10}+x^{25})^k=[x^n]\frac{x+x^{10}+x^{25}}{1-(x+x^{10}+x^{25})}$$

count the ordered ways to put coins in the machine up to $n$.

Comment: your answer is  correct, since
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {x^{\,1}  + x^{\,10}  + x^{\,25} } \right)\left( {x^{\,1}  + x^{\,10}  + x^{\,25} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = x^{\,1} x^{\,1}  + x^{\,1} x^{\,10}  + x^{\,1} x^{\,25}  +   \cr 
  &  + x^{\,10} x^{\,1}  + x^{\,10} x^{\,10}  + x^{\,10} x^{\,25}  +   \cr 
  & x^{\,25} x^{\,1}  + x^{\,25} x^{\,10}  + x^{\,25} x^{\,25}  \cr} 
$$
and that counts either $(10,1)$ and $(1,10)$.

Comment: Is there some way of keeping track of the orderings? So you would somehow modify this to provide the unordered integer partitions.

Comment: @Alexander I dont think so. Unordered count are really messy and ugly, see by example the difference between the [partition of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) and the [composition of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Luckly, there is a way to do it in at least this specific case https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454193/integer-partition-in-k-parts-from-a-specific-set-s/3454362#3454362