# Integer partition in k parts from a specific set S

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, generating-functions

This is an unordered change making problem: make change for an $n$ cent coin from coin set $S$ using exactly $k$ coins.

In terms of partitions of integers, and generating functions:

Via addition, you have to make $n$ from the numbers $S=\{0,n_1, n_2, \dots , n_m\}$ using exactly $k$ numbers.

For example, make 6 from the numbers 1,3 and 4. One way is 3+3. Another is 4+1+1. Ordered partitions consider 1+4+1 distinct, but we need unordered partitions.

Part solution: You can use the straightforward generating function

$$f(q)=(q^0+q^{n_1}+\dots+q^{n_m})^{k}$$

so the count is the coefficient of $q^n$ in the series expansion of $f(q)$. **But this does not keep track of the orderings.**

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334533/how-to-find-the-generating-function-of-the-following-problem?rq=1), for example, where the unordered solution is given.

**What is the generating function which gives unordered integer partitions (into $k$ parts from $S$)?** It seems more difficult, since you don't know how varied the coins used are. Sometimes it is many coins repeated, other times they are all different. If you can track how many distinct coins are used each time, then the problem can be solved, but that seems more tricky.

Perhaps this solvable using exponential generating functions, since they're used in finite set problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by your wording, as you're looking for unordered partitions but then complain that the generating function doesn't “keep track of the orderings”. If I understand correctly what you're looking for, you can use the generating function

$$
f(q,u)=\prod_i\left(1-uq^{n_i}\right)^{-1}\;.
$$

The coefficient of $u^kq^n$ is the number of ways to make change for $n$ with $k$ coins of the given denominations.

Comment: Sorry, my wording is unclear: it’s meant to mean to sort of count how many orderings for each partition, so as not to over count. In power group enumeration its all about counting the orderings i.e. the orbits. So I say keep track. But this essentially only gives only one count per distinct unordered partition?

Comment: @AlexanderKartun-Giles: Exactly.